# Power Bi nested list in string

Tags: powerbi

So i have the following problem:

I'm trying to import some data from my database into my report.
The data is provided by some views, which already have predetermined datatypes for my columns.
Although they are not all correct. And here lies the problem.

An example would be:

| items (type = int) | itemDetails (type = string) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [[[Fruit], Fruit, Apple, 0.90]] |
| 2 | [[[Fruit], Fruit, Apple, 0.90],[[Veggie], Veggie, Salat, 1.50]] |

Now the problem is, that Power Bi doesn't recognize the data in the second column as a list, or an array.

My goal is to extract the informations in these nested lists: so the desired output would be something like:

| items (type = int) | itemDetails | itemCategory | itemName | itemPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [[[Fruit], Fruit, Apple, 0.90]] | Fruit | Apple | 0.9 |
| 2 | [[[Fruit], Fruit, Apple, 0.90],[[Veggie], Veggie, Salat, 1.50]] | Fruit, Veggie | Apple, Salat | 0.9, 1.5 |

Comment: Is this raw data as you get it from the DB, or has it been preprocessed through PBI steps already? Because that is just a terrible format to work with no matter how you slice it, but if it comes this way through a PBI transformation it can probably be salvaged. If it does come from the database, see if you can query the base tables rather than the views for a more useful structuring of the input. Only if all else fails should you consider processing this in its current form.

Comment: The problem is, that it comes from the DB in exactly this format and i don't have much control over the source. And the base of the data is no table, but I'm accessing a materialized view on some parquet files.

Comment: Well, PBI has a Parquet connector, so it would be nice to skip out the middle man... Although you can do string manipulation in PBI, what you need to write here is practically a fully fledged parser, as this format doesn't resemble anything the built-in functions can easily process. Simply splitting by comma won't do it, nor will trying to read it as JSON. It's definitely possible (`Text.BetweenDelimiters` and then some recursion, probably), but decidedly nontrivial.

Comment: HAve you tried to split in power query?